# Prevent Emacs from deleting trailing whitespace when return key is pressed

Tags: emacs, elisp, markdown, key-bindings

To edit markdown text I use Emacs's `markdown-mode`. I'd like to express "newline" by "  " (i.e. 2 spaces). But in that situation if I go to the next line by pressing <kbd>return</kbd> key, trailing whitespaces are automatically deleted.

I want that whitespace as it is. How can I achieve that? Do I need to add any extra configuration to my `init.el`?

Comment: Not specific to your question, but you might want to look into <http://editorconfig.org/>.  Makes general stuff like this much simpler and saves you some trouble if you have coworkers or decide to switch editors later on.

Comment: Only if you rebind `RET` to somewhat else or advise `newline-and-indent`. That function just calls `(delete-horizontal-space t)` unconditionally.

Comment: Are you using Emacs 24.5 or more recent? If so, then try turning off `electric-indent-mode`, which is now turned on by default. @doublep: Consider posting your comment as an answer - combined with `electric-indent-mode`, I suspect that it is in fact the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find what <kbd>RET</kbd> is doing, you can try `C-h k RET`, which shows that <kbd>RET</kbd> is bound to `markdown-enter-key` which is clearing empty spaces at the end.

One way to solve this problem is to remove that binding in markdown mode. For that, you can add this to your config(init.el or .emacs.el).

```
(require 'markdown-mode)
(define-key markdown-mode-map (kbd "C-m") nil)
```

This prevents binding of <kbd>RET</kbd> to `markdown-enter-key` and it works like normal return

An altertanate way to achieve it is setting

```
(custom-set-variables '(markdown-indent-on-enter nil))
```

This prevents deleting whitespace automatically.

Comment: Thank you for you support !
I execute `C-h k RET`, then message is shown.

    RET runs the command markdown-enter-key, which is an interactive

    It is bound to RET. 

    (markdown-enter-key)

    Handle RET according to to the value of `markdown-indent-on-enter'.

Then let 'markdown-indent-on-enter' disabled, I archieved what I'd like to do !

    (custom-set-variables '(markdown-indent-on-enter nil))